# Javascript - base.js multiple inheritance

Tags: javascript, inheritance, multiple-inheritance

We have a very big project with thousands of js files. Now, due to requirement we need multiple inheritance in few cases. We have used http://dean.edwards.name/weblog/2006/03/base/ for base. The issue is:

We have:

```
BaseComp.js inherits Base.js

Comp1_base_2013.js inherits BaseComp.js

Comp1_1_2013.js, Comp1_2_2013.js etc. inherits Comp1_base.js

Comp1_1_2016.js inherits Comp1_1_2013.js
Comp1_2_2016.js inherits Comp1_2_2013.js ...
```

Now some changes are needed in `Comp1_base.js` which should only be applied to `Comp1_1_2016.js`,`Comp1_2_2016.js`... as 2013 and 2016 have same base.

So, how do we solve this problem?

Comment: If the changes are _only_ needed in 2013, it doesn't logically follow that 2016 should have been inheriting from 2013 in the first place - sounds like you need to break apart Comp1_base into two bases, one for 2013 and one for 2016, perhaps itself having a new base for common functionality.

Comment: 2016 is slighlty different from 2013, and 2013 contains bulk code which we don't want to rewrite. 2013 is base for 2016 but in some cases some core features differ.

Comment: In that case, pull out the bits that differ into a new 2013 and make the old 2013 a common base where things aren't different.  Base classes shouldn't really alter their behaviour based on what's inheriting from them - they shouldn't even necessarily know that they are being inherited.